# Using javascript variable in mysql query and populate listview

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a google map/marker application where I want to use the marker id in a mysql query in order to extract the data relating to the marker in a listview when the marker is clicked.

The variable is assigned when the marker is clicked and I am using ajax to transfer the value through to a php file for the variable to be used in the mysql query.

**JS**

```
function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        var site_id = marker.get("id");      
        $.ajax({
            url: 'getoffer.php',
            type: "POST",
            data: { site: site_id},
            success: getoffers
        });     
    });
}
```

On success I've called the getoffers function which populates the listview with the database values.

```
var output1 = '';       
function getoffers() {
    $.post( "getoffer.php?getjson", function( data ) {
        var data = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(data);
        $.each(data, function(index, value){
            output1 += '<li data-id='+ value.offer_id +'><a href="#"">' + value.offer_title + '</a></li>';  
        });
        $('#offerlist').html(output1).listview().listview('refresh');
    });
}
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
$site = $_POST['site_id'];
require("dbconnect.php");
try {
    $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$database;charset=utf8", $username, $password,
      array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"));
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}

$STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM Offer WHERE site_id='$site'");
$STH->execute();
$arr = $STH->fetchAll();
echo json_encode($arr);
die();
```

When I run the application there are no errors but the listview is blank.

When I remove the ajax code and the where clause from sql the code returns all the values in that table so I know that it works regarding the db connection and the output to listview. I must be going wrong with the variable passing in ajax or if I'm calling the code incorrectly.

Any advice is greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: You're posting a value named `site` (in the first example), but in PHP you're retrieving `site_id`. Not sure why you're posting to `getoffer.php` *again* in `getoffers()`, and without any `site` OR `site_id`. You probably just want `data` as a parameter to `getoffers()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making a seperate ajax request in the success function for some reason. The success function will already have the data passed to it, so simply remove the second ajax request:

```
function getoffers(data) {
    //$.post( "getoffer.php?getjson", function( data ) {
        var data = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(data);
        $.each(data, function(index, value){
            output1 += '<li data-id='+ value.offer_id +'><a href="#"">' + value.offer_title + '</a></li>';  
        });
        $('#offerlist').html(output1).listview().listview('refresh');
    //});
}
```

Also, as noted by @Paul Roub, your post data key does not match up with your php, either change the data in your ajax to:

```
data: { site_id: site_id},
```

**OR** change your php to use the key `site`:

```
$site = $_POST['site'];
```

Comment: and Paul Roub. Thank you gents that's fixed it for me :) I didn't realise that I was calling ajax twice. Much appreciated.